Background Image module not blurring for Anonymous Users
Issue
I have a Drupal 10 site that doesn't load some dependencies for Anonymous users and breaks the blur effect for one of my modules.
I used the Background Image module to create a page with a background image that progressively blurs the further you scroll. This uses a setting in the module:

The problem is that only authenticated users can see the blur effect. When I view the site as an Anonymous user, I can still see the image that was set using the Background Image module, but the blur effect is gone.
Error Message & Missing Module
The console shows the error:
Chrome console
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')
    at RuntimeCss.add (runtime.css.js?v=1.0.0:34:24)
    at updateOffset (scrolling.blur.js?v=1.0.0:50:15)
    at Object.attach (scrolling.blur.js?v=1.0.0:53:7)
    at drupal.js?v=10.3.2:166:24
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Drupal.attachBehaviors (drupal.js?v=10.3.2:162:34)
    at drupal.init.js?v=10.3.2:32:12
    at HTMLDocument.listener (drupal.init.js?v=10.3.2:20:7)

Firefox console
Uncaught TypeError: _ is undefined
    add http://its.test/modules/contrib/background_image/js/runtime.css.js?v=1.0.0:34
    updateOffset http://its.test/modules/contrib/background_image/js/scrolling.blur.js?v=1.0.0:50
    attach http://its.test/modules/contrib/background_image/js/scrolling.blur.js?v=1.0.0:53
    attachBehaviors http://its.test/core/misc/drupal.js?v=10.3.2:166
    attachBehaviors http://its.test/core/misc/drupal.js?v=10.3.2:162
    <anonymous> http://its.test/core/misc/drupal.init.js?v=10.3.2:32
    listener http://its.test/core/misc/drupal.init.js?v=10.3.2:20
    domReady http://its.test/core/misc/drupal.init.js?v=10.3.2:26
    <anonymous> http://its.test/core/misc/drupal.init.js?v=10.3.2:31
    <anonymous> http://its.test/core/misc/drupal.init.js?v=10.3.2:34

After looking into this further, I noticed that the core module underscore-min.js which is listed as a dependency for Background Image does not load for Anonymous users. This likely explains why _ is undefined.
Troubleshooting

Confirmed the permissions allow Anonymous Users to view background images.
Searched for permissions that might block certain scripts for Anonymous users but couldn't find any.
Confirmed that the module lists the underscore library correctly as a dependency, but this only loads for authenticated users.
Created a custom module that uses the underscore dependency and loads the core module as per the instructions in this stack overflow question.
Temporarily disabled CSS & JS aggregation and caching in case this is causing the issue.
Flushed caches and browser cache.
Temporarily uninstalled the modules Internal Dynamic Page Cache and Internal Page Cache.

Conclusion
According to my network tab in dev tools, a large number of core modules only load for Authenticated users and not Anonymous (including backbone, underscore, tabbable, loadjs, and jquery.ui). As underscore is a dependency for the Background Image module, it breaks the blur functionality for Anonymous users.
I need help understanding why this module doesn't load for Anonymous users and how to fix this.
Edit
Unfortunately, this question has been closed as Drupal stack exchange is not the right place to ask about Drupal modules or how to contribute to a patch that resolves bugs affecting Drupal modules.
I opened a bug report on the module page, but considering that the response rate is 0% and there are bugs more than 2 years old, I decided to search for a different solution or module.

I’m voting to close this question because it’s a bug report for the background image module, and needs to be handled in the module’s issue queue

I opened the bug report that you linked, and I opened this question because the module maintainer is non-responsive, so resolution of this bug may come down to me writing a patch.

We have a strict policy of not allowing bug reports or discussions about their workarounds here - it’s to ensure that all useful information about a bug is in a single place, which is predictable for everyone

It looks like the background_image has a dependency for the  core/underscore library
That was removed in Drupal 10: https://www.drupal.org/node/3273118
That module has stated it works with Drupal 10 but appears it doesn't. So you'll probably need to create your own libary to replicate underscore and add it to your theme/own module

This is great info. Do you know why the library still loads for authenticated users though? The library not only exists in core/vendors, but the network tab also shows that it loads as long as you are logged in. I'm hoping to leverage this functionality until I can write a replacement library.

I think core has created it's own library of underscore which is supposed to be for internal use only (used within core code only). core/internal.underscore thats being used on something to run the CMS for admin users and that's why it works there. I haven't checked if that still exists in D10 or core has some other library its using to replicate underscore

@GeorgeCiesinski – Can you maybe update the issue on DO with the findings, please?
